# trying to mimic *this* object, not working

Tags: function, this

I have a table with columns and rows and cells have an onclick handler.

```
<tr name="row1">
    <td name="col1" onclick="f1(this)">
    <td name="col2" onclick="f1(this)">
    <td name="col3" onclick="f1(this)">
</tr>
```

The function `f1` marks the cells as selected by the user.  This has all worked as expected.  I am trying to add the functionality that if a user has saved selections and then returns to the form, I can pre-select the correct cells saved by the user.  So I wrote this function that I can call with values of `row` and `col` from the database.

```
function f2 (row, col) {
    f1( $( 'tr[name=row'+row+']' ).find( 'td[name=col'+col+']' ) );
}
```

Only thing is, it doesn't work.  If I construct the complete string, e.g.,

```
f1( $( 'tr[name=row1]' ).find( 'td[name=col2]' )[0])
```

then it works just fine.  But it doesn't work in the page, and i'm guessing it has to do with incorrect quoting of the parameters, but I can't figure out how to correctly proceed.  How do I construct programmatic calls to `f1` ?

Comment: What are your parameters and why have you added a `[0]`?

Comment: are row/col as coming from the database numeric? If so, you still need to prefix them with "row" and "col". Function `f2` has a missing closing parenthesis.

Comment: editing OP for clarity - it was correctly pointed out that `name='+row` really should have been `name=row'+row`

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="de">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Titel</title>
    <script>
        function f2 (self) {
            var col = self.attributes["name"].value;
            var row = self.parentNode.attributes["name"].value;
            alert(row + " " + col);
            // do what you want
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
        <tr name="row1">
            <td name="col1" onclick="f2(this);">test1</td>
            <td name="col2" onclick="f2(this);">test2</td>
            <td name="col3" onclick="f2(this);">test3</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The reason i can't use Ids instead of names is that I have many more rows and I need to be able to  look at everything in col1 for example which I can do by name, but not by ID because of the uniqueness restriction.

Comment: @EddieRowe I made a change in the above answer so that you can use `name`